# Redux reducer correct way to check if item already exists in state

Tags: react-redux

I'm a little uncertain of this approach when updating an existing or adding a new object to a redux store but am having trouble getting this to work using the accepted methods i.e. Object.assign, update() or spread operators. I can get it working as follows:

```
const initialState = {
    cart: []
}

export default function cartReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case ADD_TO_CART:

            let copy = _.clone(state.cart);
            let cartitem = _.find(copy, function (item) {
                return item.productId === action.payload.productId;
            });

            if (cartitem) {
                cartitem.qty = action.payload.qty;
            } else {
                copy.push(action.payload);
            }

            return {
                ...state,
                cart: copy
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Although this works, I'm using Underscore to copy the state and check whether the item already exists in state which seems unnecessary and overkill?

Comment: Did you sort this? What does state.cart look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code for the redux. Use the .find function to find if an element is already in the array.
Example Code:

```
const inCart = state.cart.find((item) =>
        item.id === action.payload.id ? true : false
      );
 return {
        ...state,
        cart: inCart
          ? state.cart.map((item) =>
              item.id === action.payload.id
                ? { ...item, qty: item.qty + 1 }
                : item
            )
          : [...state.cart, { ...item, qty: 1 }],
      };
```

With Redux-Toolkit you can mutate the state objects so you can likely simplify this a bit.

```
const basket = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, { payload }) => {
  const inCart= state.cart.find((item) => item.id === payload.id);

      if (inCart) {
        item.qty += payload.qty;
      } else {
        state.items.push(payload);
      }
},
},
});
```